# Use custom component to set parent form control

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

I'm trying to use a custom date-picker to set a form control in my form group. The form group is AddressInProgress, and on submit a copy of the form groups value gets added to an Addresses array.

My issue is that the date-picker seems to keep a reference to all the items in the array, and when inputting the next address all the address dates in the array get changed too.

```
export class MonthYearPicker {
  @Input() date: FormControl;
  momentDate: Moment;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.momentDate = _moment(this.date.value);
  }

  chosenYearHandler(normalizedYear: _moment.Moment) {
    this.momentDate.year(normalizedYear.year());
  }

  chosenMonthHandler(normlizedMonth: _moment.Moment, datepicker: 
  MatDatepicker<_moment.Moment>) {
    this.momentDate.month(normlizedMonth.month());
    this.date.setValue(this.momentDate);
    datepicker.close();
  }
}

<div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-5 layout-row-flex">
   <month-year-picker [date]="addressInProgressControls?.occupiedUntil"></month-year-picker>
</div>
```

Comment: Clone date value before assign?

Comment: Thanks, tried this using Object.assign, no such luck.